# upload image data via ajax POST. Facing problems

Tags: ajax, image, upload

in an existing web application which uses cgi script for uploading image via form submit.
Now I have to crop a particular portion of the image and send the part to server.

Cropping and all is achieved by Canvas APIs, now I have to send the image data to the server side code which is expecting a file earlier.

I have used the dataUrl function, and also created the blob data type conversion in uploading.
But on the server side what I am getting is

> "this is my log.[object Blob]"

or

> " this is my log.[object ImageData]"

where am I going wrong ?

Note: I have set any content-Type, so the default one that is going is "Content-Type:**application/x-www-form-urlencoded**"
If I try to use "**multipart/form-data**", the data is going like

> imgtype=imgbackground&customrsp=html&file=%5Bobject%20ImageData%5D

And I am not allowed to change the server side code except for some configs.

Answer (score 0):

Canvas has the toDataURL function to return a representation of the image file, the FormData object only accepts File or Blob objects from the File API.

Check this question for details. I hope it will help: [Convert fata URI to file to append to FormData](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4998908/convert-data-uri-to-file-then-append-to-formdata)